# Swift - pass struct to a method?

Tags: swift

The following code gives a compile error because it thinks the array that was passed to the function is not mutable anymore. I know that Array is a struct and therefore passed by value instead of reference, so how do you deal with something similar to this where you pass a struct to a method and you want to be able to modify it? **Don't want to use an extension in this case.**

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
array.removeLast()
removeOne(array)

func removeOne(array: Array<AnyObject>) {
   array.removeLast()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Mike S's answer above is correct, but if you want to use this for any type you'll need a generic function:

```
func removeOne<T>(inout array: Array<T>) {
    array.removeLast()
}

var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
removeOne(&array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [in-out parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_267) to do that:

```
func removeOne(inout array: Array<String>) {
    array.removeLast()
}

var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
array.removeLast()
removeOne(&array)
```

Also note that I changed `Array<AnyObject>` to `Array<String>` since the compiler will define `var array = ["1", "2", "3"]` as `Array<String>` and won't be able to cast that to `Array<AnyObject>`.

Comment: So, `String` is not an `AnyObject`? Gotta love Swift.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate -- `Array<String>` can be cast to `Array<AnyObject>`, but since you're passing it to an `inout` function, it has to cast the `Array<AnyObject>` back to `Array<AnyObject>`, which it won't do implicitly. (It can cast back using the `as` keyword, but that isn't possible when calling an `inout` function.)

Comment: @Zaph `String` is a `struct` in Swift so it can't inherit from `AnyObject`. `Any` might have worked too though.

Comment: @NateCook I thought `String` was a `struct` and couldn't be cast to `AnyObject`. Is that not correct?

Comment: While all this is true this implementation detail of Swift should not be pushed on the user. Also consider that `String` is bridged to `NSString` which is a class and thus an Object.

Comment: Why did you put & before the array when passing?

Comment: @JohnWoods From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_267): _You place an ampersand (&) directly before a variable’s name when you pass it as an argument to an inout parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the function._